# gMaps.js pan to center map over marker that is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been looking around a lot and I use the gMaps.js 
The link is: http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/

I have a for loop that iterates through all my coords (longitude and latitude) and placed markers all other the city. The problem is I would like when I click a marker that the map centers around it.

I have tried:

```
     .click(function() {
            map.panTo(23,43);
      }
```

Also:

```
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.open(map,marker);
```

My Gmap area is as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tell").hide();
        map = new GMaps({
        div: '#googleMap',
        lat: listRecCenters[4].latitude,  //property map (city) in list at array index 4 no quotes
        lng: listRecCenters[4].longitude,
        zoom: 10,
    }); 

    for(i = 0; i < listRecCenters.length; i++)
    {
        map.addMarker({
        lat: listRecCenters[i].latitude,
        lng: listRecCenters[i].longitude,
        title: listRecCenters[i].city,
        infoWindow: {content: "<p class = \"info\"><img src = \"img/rec.jpg\" style = \"float:right;margin:-10px; padding-right:4px;padding-top:4px;width:40px; height:40px;\"></span>" + listRecCenters[i].name + "<br><span class = \"addcolor\">" + listRecCenters[i].addr
        + "<br/>" + listRecCenters[i].city + listRecCenters[i].phone + "</span>" + "<span class = \"myUrl\"><a href = \"http://maps.google.com/?q=" + listRecCenters[i].addr + " "+listRecCenters[i].city + ",Ontario, Canada\">Google Link</a><a <a href = \"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&q" + listRecCenters[i].addr + " "+listRecCenters[i].city + ",Ontario, Canada\">Lat/Long</a><a</span></p>"
     }              
  });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, nothing seems to work for being able to do this. Thanks a lot for reading my post. If you require any more answers I'll gladly post them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
map.addMarker({
  lat: -12.04,
  lng: -77.02,
  title: 'Marker with InfoWindow',
  infoWindow: {
    content: '<h3>InfoWindow Content</h3>lat: -12.04<br>lng: -77.02<br>'
  },
  click: function(e) {
    map.map.panTo(e.position);
  }
});
```

The click listener came from the [example in the documentation](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/markers.html), the `map` object is a `GMaps()` object, the [`panTo`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map) method requires a [google.maps.Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map) object, which is stored in the GMap.map property.

```js
var map = new GMaps({
  div: '#map',
  lat: -12.043333,
  lng: -77.028333
});
map.addMarker({
  lat: -12.043333,
  lng: -77.028333,
  title: 'Marker with InfoWindow',
  infoWindow: {
    content: '<h3>InfoWindow Content</h3>lat: -12.043333<br>lng: -77.028333<br>'
  },
  click: function(e) {
    map.map.panTo(e.position);
  }
});
map.addMarker({
  lat: -12.04,
  lng: -77.02,
  title: 'Marker with InfoWindow',
  infoWindow: {
    content: '<h3>InfoWindow Content</h3>lat: -12.04<br>lng: -77.02<br>'
  },
  click: function(e) {
    map.map.panTo(e.position);
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#map {
  background: #58B;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/HPNeo/gmaps/master/gmaps.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: This worked percetly!!  ,
  click: function(e) {
    map.map.panTo(e.position);
  }

Comment: Thanks can you explain? I was close using that i think. the double 'map' and 'e' confuse me